# adding new dict to json output python

Tags: python, json, twitter

Very new to json so please forgive if I am using the wrong terms here. Any ways I am trying to create a json file every x minutes with updated twitter info. Now I know i could just use the twitter api and grab what I need but I am wanting to mess around a bit. My problem is getting a new key/dict? or what ever it is called for each new item added in a for statement.

What im trying to get

```
[
  {
    "name": "thename",
    "date": "thedate",
    "text": "thetext"
  }, <--- trying to get that little comma
  {
    "name": "thename",
    "date": "thedate",
    "text": "thetext"
  }
]
```

Now i am getting the data that i want and all but not that comma. It outputs it all but not like it should be with that little one character thing that makes it valid.

```
[
  {
    "name": "thename",
    "date": "thedate",
    "text": "thetext"
  } <--- I get this instead for each new object
  {
    "name": "thename",
    "date": "thedate",
    "text": "thetext"
  }
]
```

Here is just a snippet of the code as the rest should be explanatory since its just Twitter oauth stuff.

```
for player in users:
    statuses = api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name=player, count=10)
    print "["

    for s in statuses:
            print json.dumps('timestamp': s.created_at,'username': s.user.name,'status': s.text)
    print "]"
```

Also is there a better way to do the [ ] at the start and end because I know that is ugly and way un-proper i bet XD . Like I said newbie on json/python stuff but its a good learning experience.

Comment: You're not actually print the comma in your for loop. However, @poke's answer is way to go. Let json handle the whole json message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to build the JSON array yourself, you should just let the JSON encoder do that for you too. To do that, you just need to pass a list of objects to `json.dumps`. So instead of printing each JSON object on its own, just collect them in a list, and dump that:

```
allstatuses = []
for player in users:
    statuses = api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name=player, count=10)
    for s in statuses:
        allstatuses.append({'timestamp': s.created_at, 'username': s.user.name, 'status': s.text})

print(json.dumps(allstatuses))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, i knew there had to be a better way. Just could not find a good tutorial on it. Thank poke.